# to_csv makes 0 disappear

Tags: excel, csv

I have this code

```
y_predicted = model.predict_classes(X_test)
df = pd.DataFrame(y_predicted)
df.columns = ['label']
df.to_csv("2nd_prediction.csv", index_label="index")
```

When I open the `2nd_prediction.csv` file in Excel, values of zero disappear (e.g. it was like 13,0 (13 - index, 0 - label), but I got 13,).

I tried to use

```
na_rep = "0"
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: What is the output of `df.to_csv(index_label="index")`? Can you see the "missing zeros"?

Comment: Suddenly, but yes, I can

Comment: Then the problem is in how Excel displays your CSV files. It has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Well, perhaps, but when I upload my prediction on Kaggle, it returns an error, e.g. Record 14 had 1 column but expected 2

Comment: Ah, well, reuploaded it and it's fine thou

Comment: @PaulSnopov So, the problem is resolved?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to "close" question?

Comment: you can simply delete it